# TikZ random steps decoration "along a grid"

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to create certain TikZ-images in which I have random paths from one point to another, such that these random paths follow a square grid. More precisely, I would like to adjust the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0.5,0) to (0.5,3);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,0.5) to (3,0.5);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (2.5,0) to (2.5,3);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,2.5) to (3,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code yields this (random) picture:

[image]

Now, I would wish to have the random (olive-colored) paths to follow along a square grid, meaning that the random steps should only be along horizontal and vertical directions.

I have consulted the PGF-TikZ-manual but it didn't appear that there is any direct option for this kind of behaviour.

Is there an east way to obtain this, at best using the decoration.pathmorphing library instead of some hand-written algorithm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Welcome to TeX-SE! You could just slightly modify the decoration to get what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{vertical random steps}{start}
{%
  \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=step,persistent precomputation=\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue]{}%
  \state{step}[auto end on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               auto corner on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  {
    \pgfpathlineto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{0pt}{rand*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
    }
  }%
  \state{final}
  {}%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={vertical random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0.5,0) to (0.5,3);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={vertical random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,0.5) to (3,0.5);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={vertical random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (2.5,0) to (2.5,3);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={vertical random steps,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,2.5) to (3,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that decorations transform you in tangent space, i.e. the second direction is along the normal (and the first along the tangent).

In principle, you do not need a decoration here, you could just use `plot` with `samples at` and add `rnd` noise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,2);

  \draw [olive,thick] plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,0.1,...,2.9,3}] 
  ({0.5cm+3pt*(2*rnd-1)},\x)
  plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,0.1,...,2.9,3}] 
  ({2.5cm+3pt*(2*rnd-1)},\x)
  plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,0.1,...,2.9,3}] 
  (\x,{0.5cm+3pt*(2*rnd-1)})
  plot[variable=\x,samples at={0,0.1,...,2.9,3}] 
  (\x,{2.5cm+3pt*(2*rnd-1)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another attempt to make you happy.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{fixed snake}{start}
{%
  \state{start}[width=+0pt,next state=step,
  persistent precomputation=\pgfdecoratepathhascornerstrue
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mysegmentlength}{%
  int(\pgfdecoratedpathlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)*%
  \pgfdecorationsegmentlength*\pgfdecorationsegmentlength/\pgfdecoratedpathlength}
  \setlength\pgfdecorationsegmentlength{\mysegmentlength pt}
  ]{}%
  \state{step}[auto end on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               auto corner on length=1.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
               width=+\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]
  { 
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\myint}{1}{2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myrand}{sign(\myint-1.5)*\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}
    \pgfpathlineto{
      \pgfpointadd
      {\pgfpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
      {\pgfpoint{0pt}{\myrand pt}}
    }
    \pgfpathlineto{
      \pgfpoint{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\myrand pt}
    }
  }%
  \state{final}[width=0pt]
  {%\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{-\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0pt}}
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }%
}%


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[clip] (0,0) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw (1,1) rectangle (2,2);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={fixed snake,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0.5,0) to (0.5,3.5);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={fixed snake,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,0.5) to (3.5,0.5);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={fixed snake,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (2.5,0) to (2.5,3.5);
  \draw [olive,thick, decorate, decoration={fixed snake,segment
    length=5pt,amplitude=3pt}] (0,2.5) to (3.5,2.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If that's again not what you're after, please consider explaining in precise terms what you want. If you provide very clear prescriptions for what you want to get, I am optimistic to find a way to implement it.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer, but apparently I was not precise enough: I would like to have the green line such that its tangent is always parallel to either the horizontal or vertical axis (so it should look like in the video game "snake")

Comment: So the whole thing should look a bit like a lattice random walk: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#/media/File:Random_walk_2500.svg

Comment: @PeterWildemann I added something. The Wikipedia thingy has steps that are in random directions but have always the same (as opposed to a random) amplitude. Is that what you're after? Please consider making your question as precise as possible.

Comment: Yes! It should always have the same amplitude. It tried to make this clear by stating that "these random paths follow a square grid".

Comment: @PeterWildemann Sorry, this does still not specify where the path should end. (I misinterpreted  "these random paths follow a square grid" as the statement that the decorated paths should follow a square grid, which they do.)

Comment: Okay, let me try to elaborate. I wrote that I wish for "random paths from one point to another, such that these random paths follow a square grid". So I would like to specify a width/height of a cartesian grid (= square grid), choose two vertices A and B on that grid and then generate a (not too wild, at best non-self-intersecting) random path from A to B along the edges of the grid. What is important here, is that there is one fixed width/height of the grid, which should also specify the amplitude of the random steps. If you wish further elaboration, I can also post a picture!

Comment: In mathematical terms, I am looking for a method to sample a discrete (i.e. with prescribed step-size), non-self-intersecting, Brownian Bridge from one grid vertex to another.

Comment: You are a magician! Thank you!